# I want to Reorder Rows in an ExtJs grid?

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, grid, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJs 4.2 and I have a Ext.grid.Panel and I have data coming in, but i want them to be ordered upon ingestion based on a boolean flag with things that have true for one field at the top, true for another field next, with false in both fields coming at the bottom. So far I have editing the sorters as prescribed below.

```
me.requesterListStore = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'requesterListStore',
        model: 'Connex.Request.Model.RequesterModel',
        buffered: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        leadingBufferZone: 50,
        autoLoad: false,
        remoteFilter: false,
        purgePageCount: 5,
        remoteSort: false,
        sortOnLoad: true,
        sorters: [
            {
                property: 'isSmartIndexed',
                direction: 'DESC'
            },
            {
                property: 'isAutoIndexed',
                direction: 'DESC'
            }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: $context + 'services/requester/search',
            actionMethods: {
                read: 'POST'
            },
            doRequest: function (operation, callback, scope) {

                var writer = this.getWriter(),
                    request = this.buildRequest(operation, callback, scope);

                if (operation.allowWrite()) {
                    request = writer.write(request);
                }

                Ext.apply(request, {
                    headers: this.headers,
                    timeout: this.timeout,
                    scope: this,
                    callback: this.createRequestCallback(request, operation, callback, scope),
                    method: this.getMethod(request),
                    jsonData: this.jsonData,
                    disableCaching: false // explicitly set it to false, ServerProxy handles caching
                });
                Ext.Ajax.request(request);
                return request;
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'content',
                totalProperty: 'total',
                idProperty: 'id'
            },
            writer: {
                writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
                    getRecordData: function (record) {
                        return record.data;
                    }
                })
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Is the grid connected to a store? is the store buffered?

Comment: Sorry, yes the grid is connected to a Store. And the store is set Buffered: true.

Comment: So your sort is on store not on grid

Comment: Perhaps, I am new to extJs working on a very large legacy project. I'm kinda learning as I go. But so far I have not been able to find anyone else who wants to do this, nor have I found this use case in the documentation. every sorting function i've found seems to do nothing. Also yes I have this function on the Store, now that I look. It is the information in the store I'd like to sort so that it shows up in a certain order on the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sorters: [{
    property: 'isSmartIndexed',
    direction: 'DESC' // or 'ASC'
}, {
    property: 'isAutoIndexed',
    direction: 'DESC' // or 'ASC'
}]
```

Add these sorters to your store.

True is always bigger than false ;)

Keep attenction, you can't use sortingFuntions on a bufferedStore like written here:

> If the store is buffered, then prefetchData is stored by index, this invalidates all of the prefetchedData.

because in your case you will order only the displayed data on the grid, and not the others that will be loaded.

[Test it in this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mbh).

Comment: I will try this! Thank you so much for your detailed response!

Comment: When I test this out in the fiddle it works perfectly. However when I try it in my application it has no effect. I originally thought my browser was cached but the new code shows up in the devTools. Everything seems to come in the same order. I thought at first this was due to the field not being present in the grid display but when I removed this from the fiddle it still worked. I will take another look at it and keep plugging away, but if you have any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Would it matter if 'isSmartIndexed' was a converted boolean value from a Ext.data.Model?

Comment: no I think so, update the code of your question with code of the store and the grid if you can, ty